# Select highest id given in the list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a list of multiple ids (ex. (5,8,9)).

I would like to find in a table the highest datas with the ids the list.

ex. In ma table I have some records with the highest id is 8 (9 doesn't exist in this table).
So it needs to return all records where `id_link` = 8.

the id list is obviously dynamic.

How can I make this request ?

---

Other ex:

My table :

```
id | id_link | name

1  |    5    | name_1
2  |    8    | name_2
3  |    8    | name_3
4  |    8    | name_4
```

In my request, I would like to give this list of ids : (5,8,9).

So it should return me all values with the highest existing id in the list.

In this case all rows with `id_link` = 8

Comment: When you use the word ids do you refer to the id colum of a table or the values in a column are ids?

Comment: @t1f I have edit my post with a better example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
select max(id_link) from tablename
where id_link in (5, 8, 9)
```

returns the max of the `id_links` in the list that exists in your table.
So use it like this:

```
select *
from tablename
where id_link = (
  select max(id_link) from tablename
  where id_link in (5, 8, 9)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o7vGtZsZaNvP32wiUgWMg1/0).
Results:

```
| id  | id_link | name   |
| --- | ------- | ------ |
| 2   | 8       | name_2 |
| 3   | 8       | name_3 |
| 4   | 8       | name_4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for your three values, and they may or may not match any rows. As you said, there is no row with id 23, so that will not return anything. But you can still include the value in the search.

Then return the MAX(id) from those values that were found.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM MyTable WHERE id IN (8, 12, 23);
```

If you want the whole row, not just the MAX(id) you can do this:

```
SELECT id, ... FROM MyTable WHERE id IN (8, 12, 23)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```